# Angular ng-pattern for date not working on IE9

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs, angularjs-directive, ng-pattern

I am trying to use below date (mm/dd/yyyy) validation pattern using ng-pattern in view.

```
 ng-pattern="/^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})$/"
```

As soon as I start typing the date the validation error appears and stays even after having valid date such as 10/15/1988

I tried passing it through controller using var (as shown below) but behaves the same:

In Controller:

```
  $scope.myPattern = "/^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})$/";
```

In View:

```
  ng-pattern="{{myPattern}}"
```

**Note: This both approach not working only in IE9**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about:

```
 /^((\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})|(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4}))$/
```

This will work with both dd/mm/yyyy and yyyy-mm-dd

```
/^((\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})|(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4}))$/.test('04/04/1974')
true
/^((\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})|(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4}))$/.test('1974-04-04')
true
```

Comment: Thanks Martin. I noticed that with above pattern we can put any numbers for month and date which I want to limit between (1-12) & (1-31) so I am using regex as `/^((0[1-9]|1[012])[\/](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[\/](19|20)[0-9]{2})*$/` for mm/dd/yyyy so how can i use this to allow both mm/dd/yyyy and yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: This helps me a lot to build my own expression. I also needed validate time, so my pattern results like `/^((0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[\/](0[1-9]|1[012])[\/](19|20)[0-9]{2})\s(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3])(:([0-5][0-9])){2}$/`. So thanks both for help.

Comment: Aramillo can you please mention above expression for which format ?

Answer (score 4):

Your Regex pattern should be `ng-pattern="/^(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4})$/"`. This would match dates that look like `mm/dd/yyyy`

Comment: Some how on chrome it works only if use it as ng-pattern="/^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})$/" for mm/dd/yyyy but doesn't work in IE. I already tried what you suggested here but that doesn't work in IE and other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

The solution i found for my problem was similar. The regex bellow accepts any date in the format dd/mm/yyyy, whit the year ranging from 1990 to 2020.

```
<input name="birthDate"
            ng-pattern='/^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\/(0?[1-9]|1[012])\/(19\d\d|20[12]\d)$/' ng-model="newUser.birthDate" type="text">
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you didn't bind your ng-pattern to a variable in the controller in the proper Angular way ;)

Instead of:
  $scope.myPattern = "/^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})$/";

It should be: **$scope.myPattern = new RegExp(/^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})$/);**